# Assign Vector element to a char variable

Tags: c++, vector

I have a string like this "HappyDays".

Initially I was converting this string into an array of characters.Afterwards I assign each char array element to a char variable and Then I used to check whether each character is an ASCII char or not by putting a check like this:

```
             input character <127 && input character >=0
```

Now instead of making a character array , I am making a character vector. Now I want to do the same thing that I want access a particular element of a vector using vector.at(counter). After this I want to assign this value to char variable and put an ASCII check like above. But when I do this it gives me lots of errors.

Is this the correct way of assigning a vector element value to a char variable? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does your code look like where you are using the vector? What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Technically ASCII only goes up to 127.

Comment: All this time I thought ASCII went from 0 to 127.

Comment: Also, if you have a string, why not use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for something like this (not tested):

```
std::string str("HappyDays");
std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) 
{ 
  char c = vec.at(i);
  if (c < 127 && c >=0) 
  { 
     std::cout << "character " << c << " is ASCII according to OP\n"
  }
}
```

but this also works:

```
std::string str("HappyDays");
for (auto c: str) 
{ 
  if (0 <= c && c <= 127) 
  { 
     std::cout << "character " << c << " is ASCII\n"
  }
}
```

with iterators:

```
std::string str("HappyDays");
for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) 
{ 
  char c = *it;
  if (0 <= c && c <= 127) 
  { 
     std::cout << "character " << c << " is ASCII\n"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but in a for loop I want to make use of iterator and access specific elements of the vector. How can I achieve that. As this way of iteration doesn't give me a counter value like 0,1 2 etc? (like the value of indcies when accessing array elements)

Comment: I added an example with iterators (same for vector)